# How can I convert it to Java lambda format?

Tags: java, lambda

I am writing Java code
I would like to replace the for statement below with Java lambda code.
How can I do this?

Thank you.

```java
public void test() {
    List<Integer> sellIdList = Arrays.asList(2, 1);
    List<List<Integer>> settingIdListByGroup = Arrays.asList(
            Arrays.asList(4, 7, 3, 2, 9), Arrays.asList(8, 21, 1, 15, 13));

    for(List<Integer> settingIdList : settingIdListByGroup) {
        for(int i = 0; i < settingIdList.size(); i++) {
            for(int sellId : sellIdList) {
                if(settingIdList.get(i) == sellId) {
                    settingIdList.set(i, -1);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    log.debug("{}", settingIdListByGroup);
}
```

result :  `[[4, 7, 3, -1, 9], [8, 21, -1, 15, 13]]`

Comment: Hey! Have you tried that yourself already? And what went wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `sellIdList` would be much better off as a `Set` if you're wanting to check for matches within it.

You'll need two map operations. The inner one will map each inner list to a new one with elements replaced with `-1`. The outer will just collect these lists into a new one.

For example

```java
final Set<Integer> sellIdSet = Set.of(2, 1);
final List<List<Integer>> settingIdListByGroup = List.of(
        List.of(4, 5, 3, 2, 9), List.of(8, 21, 1, 15, 13));

final List<List<Integer>> newList = settingIdListByGroup.stream()
        .map(settingIdList -> settingIdList.stream()
                .map(i -> sellIdSet.contains(i) ? -1 : i)
                .collect(Collectors.toList()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I wouldn't recommend trying to replace the values in the original lists. For that you would have to use a plain `for` loop anyway.